# ABNF grammar to Java code generator?

Tags: java, code-generation, bnf

The CIM MOF has a published ABNF for MOF.
Need a tool/library to generate MOF-to-Java beans converter.

WBEMservices is a dead project which has mofcompiler.
Aware of ANTLR but need something simple & with lesser learning curve

Comment: Well, applause for packing the largest number of acronyms into the first sentence I've seen to date. I have no idea what any of it means, but I trust that it all makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) might do what you want. It's simpler to learn as specifications embed Java code.

A good tutorial to start is [this](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javacc/).